# GCP Cannot enable Cloud Build on GCP Console with Roles: Owner, Service Management Administrator, Service Usage Admin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Not able to enable Cloud Build on the project that I am assigned as Owner. I get an error message: "You are missing the required permission: billing.accounts.list" as in following screen-shot

[image]

Comment: Try to add (or if you have an Organization tell the Organization admin to add you such permissions) either the Billing Account Viewer or preferably the Billing Account User roles to your user. Find more information about the specific rolea [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access).

Comment: Hi, thank you Daniel. Assigning roles mentioned in my answer with gcloud solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by assigning the roles with gcloud on the terminal.
There must be some glitches on Google Console.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GC_PROJECT \  
--member "serviceAccount:$GC_PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role roles/run.admin

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
$GC_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--member="serviceAccount:$GC_PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GC_PROJECT \
--member "serviceAccount:$GC_PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role roles/owner
```